# @Retryable with @Scheduled don't fire

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-retry

I've written a Spring Boot Application where I've enabled Spring Batch Scheduling and Retriable as follow:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@EnableRetry
public class FilldashboardApp {

}
```

I've defined a controller as follow:

```
@Component
public class JobRunnerStats {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/2 * ? * *")
    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 10, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    protected JobExecution runJob() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        JobParameters jobParameters = null;
        if (this.jobParameters == null) {
            jobParameters = buildJobParameters(null);   
        } else {
            jobParameters = this.jobParameters;
            this.jobParameters = null;
        }
    
        return simpleJobLauncher.run(this.jobStats, jobParameters);
    }

}
```

After 2 minutes, as the cron expression specified starts the job, so in the first step of it I'll send it in exception so in the job execution and step I've tracked the `FAILED` status.

So, as the @Retryable annotation explains, I'm waiting to recall the job after 1 second (delay = 1000 microseconds) but the next access in the method is after 2 minutes (so, when the cron expression has matched)

I don't know where my fault

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Spring boot <spring-boot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version> / So Spring Batch 4.2.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/94) on Spring Retry.
Most likely the problem you are experiencing is a Spring bug ([SPR-16196](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20744)) fixed only in versions 4.3.14, 5.0.3
I tried your snippet without using Spring Batch and it works fine.

```
@Component
public class TestComponent {
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestApplication.class);

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 10, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/2 * ? * *")
    public void foo() {
        logger.info("foo");
        throw new RuntimeException("runtime");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include all expected exceptions as retryable param?

```
  @Retryable(maxAttempts = 10, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000),value={JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException.class})
```

I read a few tutorials and I'm not sure how retryable behaves when no exception (expected) were specified

Comment: Hi dear, I've read if I've not put the value parameter all exceptions are managed

Comment: When I specified the expected exception everything worked fine, using all your expected exceptions here (of course, they are not the same but they follow the same idea)

Comment: from https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html Exception types that are retryable. Synonym for includes(). Defaults to empty (and if excludes is also empty all exceptions are retried).

Comment: I see! I've never reach that part of the doc until now!

Comment: Spring boot <spring-boot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

Comment: So Spring Batch 4.2.1.RELEASE